# Having Trouble Taking information From .txt File and putting it in a .csv file in C

Tags: c

This is for a school project and I am having quite some difficulty with it. I am working in Visual Studio 2012. I am very new to C so sorry in advance.

Project Over View

Take Data from a text file (Manhattan_temp_data.txt) and write it into a .csv file (TemperatureData.csv). The ultimate goal is to have a spread sheet that can be used to create a visual representation of the temperature data for 1 year in Manhattan.

My text file looks as follows (Exactly 366 Lines)

```
Year    Month    Day Mean 
1896    5   1    61.5
1896    5   2    63
1896    5   3    64.5 
1896    5   4    -99   <The -99 means no collected data>
```

My .csv file looks as follows

```
Year \t Month \t Day \t Mean \t Interpolated Mean
```

Here is My Code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

//Structure for my Text file read
typedef struct TempTXTData{ 
    int Year; 
    int Month; 
    int Day; 
    double Mean; 
} TempTXTData_t; 

int main ()
{

FILE *FPT; //Represents My Text File 
FILE *FPC; //Represents My .csv File
int i; 
TempTXTData_t TempData[366]; 

//Where I open both my text and .csv files 
FPT= fopen("Manhattan_temp_data.txt", "r"); 
  if( FPT == NULL )
   {
      printf("Load Failure Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
FPC= fopen("TemperatureData.csv", "w");
 if( FPC == NULL ) 
   {
      fclose(FPT);
      printf("Load Failure Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 //Function where I take data from my .txt file and input it into my .csv file
 for(i=1; i<366 && fscanf(FPT, "%f %f %f %f", &TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean) !=4; i++) 
{
    for (i=1; i<366; i++) 
        fprintf(FPC, "%f, %f, %f, %f \n",&TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean);
 }


//Closing Files 
fclose(FPT); 
fclose(FPC); 

getch(); 
return 0;  
}
```

Problems

When I run the code I get and open my excel sheet all my rows and columns are the same. The first Three Columns are all 0 while the final column is -9.3E+61.

My guess is that I am not getting the data from my .txt file which makes me believe I have an error in this line...

```
 for(i=0; i<366 && fscanf(FPT, "%f %f %f %f", &TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month,    &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean) !=4; i++)
```

Thanks for your Time,

Alex

Comment: `fprintf()` doesn't automatically add newlines. Shouldn't CSV files be delimited by comma? If both the input and output files use the same delimiter `tab` then conversion is unnecessary.

Comment: Is the file content you posted, copied and pasted? Your do you get the input files from?

Comment: I Had to copy and paste the .txt data into a word file, but I made sure to save the word file a .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a newline character at the end of the format string this way

```
fprintf(FPC, "%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t\n",&TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean);
                                  /*  ^ this character is newline.
```

And since your `Year`, `Month` and `Day` are `int`'s you have to use the `%d` specifier

```
fprintf(FPC, "%d \t %d \t %d \t %f \t\n",&TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean);
```

And you dont pass the address of the fields to `fprintf` but instead the fields **remove the `&`**

```
fprintf(FPC, "%d \t %d \t %d \t %f \t\n", TempData[i].Year, TempData[i].Month, TempData[i].Day, TempData[i].Mean);
```

And a suggestion, check that `fscanf` read exactly the number of arguments you want to read in your case change this

```
fscanf(FPT, "%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t", &TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean) !=EOF
```

to this

```
fscanf(FPT, "%d \t %d \t %d \t %f \t\n", &TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month, &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean) != 4
```

since `fscanf` returns the number of items succesfully matched, from the Linux manual pages

Also, your `fscanf` will fail with the first line of your file, thus not updating the stream pointer staying at the beginig of the file, so you must read the entire line and use `sscanf` otherwise you will not be able to skip the first line and continue reading, instead your code will abort reading at the first line and you will end up with an empty file.

```
RETURN VALUE
   These  functions  return  the  number  of  input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early
   matching failure.

   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is also returned if a  read
   error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.
```

One more thing, your format string could be

```
"%d\t%d\t%d\t%f\n"
```

you don't need the extra spaces and the last `\t` character.

This code, should do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Structure for my Text file read
typedef struct TempTXTData{
    int Year;
    int Month;
    int Day;
    double Mean;
} TempTXTData_t;

int main ()
{
    FILE *FPT; //Represents My Text File
    FILE *FPC; //Represents My .csv File
    int i;
    int done;
    TempTXTData_t TempData[366];

    //Where I open both my text and .csv files
    //FPT= fopen("Manhattan_temp_data.txt", "r");
    FPT = fopen("data.dat", "r");
    if (FPT == NULL)
    {
        printf("Load Failure Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FPC= fopen("TemperatureData.csv", "w");
    if( FPC == NULL )
    {
        fclose(FPT);
        printf("Load Failure Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    done = 0;
    for (i = 1 ; (i < 366) && (done == 0) ;  i++)
    {
        char  buffer[1024];
        char *pointer;
        /* using fgets is better as was mentioned in other answers */
        pointer = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), FPT);
        if (pointer != NULL)
        {
            int matched;
            matched = sscanf(pointer, "%d%d%d%lf", &(TempData[i].Year), &(TempData[i].Month), &(TempData[i].Day), &(TempData[i].Mean));
            if (matched == 4)
                fprintf(FPC, "%d,%d,%d,%f\n", TempData[i].Year, TempData[i].Month, TempData[i].Day, TempData[i].Mean);
        }
        else
            done = 1;
    }


    //Closing Files
    fclose(FPT);
    fclose(FPC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still having an issue with pulling my values from the .txt file. I basically have only one number populating my .csv file. Would you know why the code is not pulling all the data?

Comment: @AlexMcKean don't modify the question because you break the already given answers.

Comment: sorry still new to this and didn't realize not to do that.

Comment: `fscanf(FPT, "%d \t %d \t %d \t %f \t\n"` is mis-leading as it does the same thing as `fscanf(FPT, "%d %d %d %f "`.  All the various white-spaces do the same thing: consume white-space.  Further `"%d"` and `"%f"` consume leading white-space by themselves so code could be `fscanf(FPT, "%d%d%d%f"`

Answer (score 3):

There are few things but yet, no solution (can't test right now):

- C array are indexed from `0` to `size - 1` (which you actually do using `<` operator), so your loop should iterate from `0`. Either you want to avoid the comment text, in that case you should keep the start index to `1` and store in `TempData[i-1]` otherwize, change the index to `0`.
- There is no reason for your datatypes for year / month / day not to be `int`.
- The Spreadsheet is uninteresing here. First of all, you should look at the CSV file. There might be something to configure for excel to parse the data correctly.
- Finally, and since you get an error because of that, your input file `Manhattan_temp_data.txt` should be opened read only (`r`).
- Bonus one, I know that you windows guys have to put some C function to avoid closing terminal, but you should at least use a more standard function, such as `getchar()`. Doesn't cost much for you, and will compile on other operating systems as well.

Hope this will help you a bit, or at least to edit your post to fit the actual problems.

Answer (score 2):

You edited the question potentially destroying previous answers, which is not a good manoeuvre.

Since you changed the year, month, day elements into `int` (from `double`), you have to change the `scanf()` and `printf()` strings.  One of the gotchas with `scanf()` is that `%f` is for reading `float` values and `%lf` is for reading `double` values, but `printf()` uses `%f` for printing both (because `float` values are converted to `double` during the function call).

You don't skip the heading line of the file; that's a problem.

Were it me, I'd read a line at a time using `fgets()` and then scan the line that was read with `sscanf()`.  This allows me to detect mis-formatted data more easily.

It seems curious that the years you're dealing with have but 128 days; most of the ones I encounter have 365 or 366 (a problem now fixed in the question!).

Don't test `fscanf()` for EOF; test for 'gave me the correct number of values'.

Arrays in C start at index 0.

Your code nests the input and output loops; this is mildly disastrous since you print 366 result values for the first row read, then another 366 for the next row read, and so on.  Note that most of those values are undefined; they needn't be zeros or anything useful like that. You only want to print after you've read everything (especially when you get to interpolate missing values).  You don't want to print addresses.  You do want to print newlines.

```
enum { MAX_DAYS_PER_YEAR = 366 };

char line[4096];

/* Skip header line */
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), FPT) == 0)
{
    fputs("Empty file!\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
}

/* Read up to 366 input lines */
for (i = 0; i < MAX_DAYS_PER_YEAR; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(FPT, "%d %d %d %lf", &TempData[i].Year, &TempData[i].Month,
               &TempData[i].Day, &TempData[i].Mean) != 4)
        break;
}

/* Print only the lines that were read */
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    fprintf(FPC, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%.2f\n", TempData[i].Year, TempData[i].Month,
            TempData[i].Day, TempData[i].Mean);
```

This produces tab-separated data (a TSV file), but it is common to refer to such files as CSV files, even though the C is blatantly inaccurate.  (DSV for 'delimiter separated values' is an accurate but rare term for such files.  The output file is a DSV with tab delimiters, in contrast to a DSV with comma separators.)

Comment: Thanks for the Help! Sorry for reediting answers still new to this. I tried your approach, but only get -858993460 in every row and column.

Comment: Suggest 1) `fscanf(FPT, "%d %d %d %lf"`  `TempData[i].Mean` is `double`. 2) `fprintf(FPC, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%e\n"` FP format, not %d.  IMO %e more useful here than %f

Comment: @chux: Thanks — I forgot to correct what I said needed correcting, and over-corrected (and didn't compile). I agree with the `%lf` in the input.  On output, I think `%.2f` makes sense (print to 2 decimal places), and would go with 1 without qualms.  Often `%e` makes sense, but I'm not wholly sure about it this time.